# Why doesn't iostream work for me in visual studio community?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing my first program and its not working. I'm using Microsoft visual studio community and I made a console application project. I'm reading Programming prinicples and practice using c++ and I wrote exactly what it says. why isn't it working?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }


int main()
{
    cout << "Hell, World!\n";
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's not working?  Does it compile? Link? Run?  If it runs, what is the behavior?

Comment: how you want it to run?

Comment: it says unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add #include "stdafx.h" to your source?

Comment: Turn off the precompiled header option and try again.

Comment: @H.Wang Well, you've chosen that option for precompiled header files. It's special for MSVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid precompiled headers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7261707/3425536) and [Unexpected end of file error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8862840/3425536). Why didn't you google the error message?

Comment: Why didn't you _read_ the error message???

Answer (score 3):

As from you comments clarification:

> ```
> unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header.
> Did you forget to add #include "stdafx.h" to your source?
> ```

Your project properties claim for *Precompiled Headers* (maybe it's the default for newly created projects, can't remember exactly).

So just following the advice from the error message and including

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

at the first line of your `.cpp` file should fix the error.

Comment: Why not just disable the precompiled headers option?

Comment: @zenith: Why not just add the include?