# Trying to build OpenNN for use in C# with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, opennn

[Link](https://github.com/Artelnics/OpenNN) to the source. [Link](http://www.opennn.net/documentation/building_opennn.html#VisualCplusplus) to the build instructions.

1. I create a new DLL C++ library project for .NET 4.7.
2. I go into the properties and add the eigen directory (a dependency) to the "Additional Include Directories" and "Additional #using Directories".
3. I add all of the .h files in the opennn directory to the project's "Header Files" directory and all of the .cpp files to the project's "Source Files" directory.
4. I attempt to build the project and get a ton of the same error. I find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862840/unexpected-end-of-file-error), selecting every file in the Source Files directory, going into properties, and setting "Precompiled Header" to "Not Using Precompiled Headers".
5. The build is running fine for a bit, with a bunch of signed/unsigned mismatch warnings I can ignore.
6. I get a boatload of errors.

   ```
   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 172
   syntax error: missing ';' before '*' ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 172
   'performance_functional_pointer': undeclared identifier ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 172
   'get_performance_functional_pointer': is not a member of 'OpenNN::TrainingStrategy' ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 172
   'performance_functional_pointer': undeclared identifier ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 174
   left of '->get_neural_network_pointer' must point to class/struct/union/generic type ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 174
   'maximum_iterations_number': undeclared identifier ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 238
   'MaximumIterations': is not a member of 'OpenNN::ThresholdSelectionAlgorithm' ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 247
   'MaximumIterations': undeclared identifier ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 247
   'final_binary_classification_test': is not a member of 'OpenNN::InformednessOptimizationThreshold::InformednessOptimizationThresholdResults' ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 275
   'maximum_iterations_number': undeclared identifier ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 316
   'maximum_time': undeclared identifier ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 325
   'maximum_time': undeclared identifier ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 449
   'set_maximum_iterations_number': identifier not found ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 527
   'set_maximum_time': identifier not found ~ informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp ~ 546
   ```

How do I achieve my end goal of calling OpenNN functions from C#?

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled OpenNN with flowing procedure.

1. remove informedness_optimization_threshold.cpp, informedness_optimization_threshold.h from project.
2. Add tinyxml2.cpp, tinyxml2.h in tinyxml2 folder to project.

I think it's not a good solution but may be we need more update of OpenNN.