# Visual Studio C++ compiler error "Unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header", even when including "pch.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using precompiled headers in my Visual Studio (2019) C++ project, and am including "pch.h" at the top of my source files, have `#pragma once` at the top of each header file, and a pch.cpp file (generated by the project template). Yet for one of the source files I get compiler error C1010: "Unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?" What other causes are there for this error?

Comment: Have you added `#pragma once` (include guard) on top of the header file?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I should have mentioned that before; edited.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32588641/5517378).

Comment: I recommend backing up and then playing a few rounds of divide and conquer on the file that's giving you grief. If hacking the file down to a [mcve] doesn't show you what the problem is, post the resulting code.

Comment: The precompiled header file name can be configured for each source file. The default used to be `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Do you have a .cpp file (just one) in the project that *creates* the precompiled header, rather than *using* it?

Comment: @Adrian yes, pch.cpp is there.

Comment: @Mark Ransom the default in the project template I used was pch.h; maybe this is an update.

Comment: @NutCracker I do prefer pre-compiled headers though, rather than disabling them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a corrupt cpp source file (a different one from where the error was occurring), caused by an earlier sudden power failure. It seems that once I recreated the corrupt file, the project was back into a valid state and the error went away the next time I built. ...It was a bit of a corner case, but you might clean/rebuild and check that nothing is corrupt.